# How to make Blender use the gtx1050ti as compute device in linux?

Tags: gpu, linux

I checked if the nvidia display drivers for gtx1050ti for linux OS are correctly installed and they are. (checked with nvidia-settings, glxinfo and lspci)

However, when I go to user preferences -> system, the compute device is set to CPU and I can not choose anything else.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cuda%20linux

Comment: This is already answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88588/missing-cuda-option/90434#90434