# Missing CUDA option

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

I am running Blender 2.76b on Kubuntu 16.04. I am using proprietary drivers at version 375.85 and my graphic card is GTX 1070. From what I read the drivers are recent enough and 3 years old Blender had already the CUDA support.

Any ideas what is wrong?

PS: I assume drivers are alright, because GPU acceleration is working fine in games.

Comment: Version 2.76 was released in the end of 2015 and support for GTX10X0 series is available from 2.78 version

Comment: If you installed the nvidia drivers from the repository, you might not have the cuda library.

Comment: On Linux the open source drivers do not work with Cuda, you need to install the proprietary drivers for Nvidia.

Comment: @Denis Oh, official Ubuntu repository is not updating often then. I'll try installing some other way, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Windows, the proprietary driver packet does not include CUDA under Linux, you have to install it additionally, I tripped over this problem a few times myself.

You can follow these instructions, they describe the process in detail:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04